# Pandas to_csv and read_csv with column containing lists?

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, pandas

Could have sworn that I was able to serialize and read back a dataframe with a column containing lists before.

When calling `df.to_csv(path)` the column containing lists are indeed lists
When calling `pd.read_csv(path)` the column previously containing lists are now strings, but need to be lists again.

I've written a `converter` argument to handle it, but I'd like to know if there is better way.  I've tried `astype()` with `np.ndarray`, `list` and `'O'` with no luck.

Anyone know of a 'built-in' way of handling this?

Comment: Use `ast.literal_eval` as the converter? That'd handle python literals/ dicts/sets/lists/tuples and convert to the appropriate type as needed... Not sure about putting that as an answer as I'm not sure it'll work in your case

Comment: any example of your data?

Comment: @farhawa sorry it's too sensitive. Just imagine `df.columnname.loc[0] = ['item1', 'item2']` before `to_csv()` then `df.columnname.loc[0] = "['item1', 'item2']"` after `read_csv()`